# Provision Eclipse Equinox target platform via command line

Tags: eclipse, equinox, target-platform

Given a target platform definition file of the sort:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="e46" sequenceNumber="10">
  <locations>
    <location includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
      <unit id="org.eclipse.ide...." version="some version" />
      <repository location="http://someupdatesite" />
    </location>
  </locations>
  <targetJRE path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/.../JavaSE-1.8" />
</target>
```

what is the eclipse SDK command line to generate the target platform from this definition?

My current solution is fairly ugly: unpack units, unpack repositories and run the following. It works, but obviously drops all those further arguments to locations and repositories (such as source inclusion etc.) and will blow up when the list of units becomes long:

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
  -repository http://somerepository1,http://somerepository2 \
  -installIU some_bundle1/some_version1,some_bundle2/some_version2 \
  -destination $outputdir -bundlepool $outputdir \
  -p2.os linux -p2.ws gtk -p2.arch x86_64
```

What I am looking for is something along the lines of:

```
eclipse -application someEquinoxApplication \
  -targetFile $targetfile \
  -destination $outputdir -bundlepool $outputdir \
  -p2.os linux -p2.ws gtk -p2.arch x86_64
```

I am only interested in command line solutions.

Comment: Did you find a solution on your own ? I'm willing to do the same as you do :-)

Comment: No. And I left Eclipse world for good with no regrets :)